# Raspberry Pi 4 Model B ==> AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'CascadeClassifier'

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, face-recognition, cascade-classifier

I would like to try face detection but I face the following issue:

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(haar_file) 
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'CascadeClassifier'
```

I have the following system installed:

- python3 -V ==> 3.11.2
- cv2.**version** ==> 4.9.0-dev
- Raspberry Pi 4 Model B
- Pi OS Bookworm (12)
- LONG_BIT 64
- haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml ==> in the same directory where I call my file.py

In fact I reduced the code to only two lines to limit the possible issues:

```
import cv2
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml)
```

Comment: You are missing a single or double quote `haar_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')`

Comment: Indeed, in my question I missed a single quote but then I tried single and double quote and the error is exactly the same...

Comment: Try this `py -m pip install opencv-contrib-python --upgrade`

Comment: Thank you, but I tried single quote, double quote and none. Same error...

Comment: What if you try this `face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")`?